# Computing complex integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Can anyone help me out with this question:

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$. Compute $\int_{\gamma_{r}} f(z)dz$ if $r>0$ and $\gamma_{r}$ is the border of {$z \in C: |z| \leq r, Imz\geq 0$}. We walk through this half circle in positive orientation. After computing this integral compute $\int_{0}^{\inf} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} $.

Comment: Are you familiar with the residue theorem? It lets you relate the integral over the real line to the residues of $f$ provided you can show the integral over the half circle vanishes in the limit of $r \to \infty$.

Comment: Not at all because in this section we were not allowed to use the resideu theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\gamma_{r}}\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}dz = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ire^{it}}{1+r^{2}e^{2it}}dt$$

Then $$|\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ire^{it}}{1+r^{2}e^{2it}}dt| \leq \int_{0}^{\pi}|\frac{ire^{it}}{1+r^{2}e^{2it}}|dt \leq \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{r}{r^{2}-1}dt = \frac{\pi r}{r^{2}-1}$$

Observe that $$\lim_{r \rightarrow + \infty }\frac{\pi r}{r^{2}-1} = 0$$

Let $\lambda$ be te semicircumference with the diameter on the real axis, symmetric with respect to $y$-axis and of radius $r$. Then by the residue theorem $$\int_{C}\frac{1}{1+z^{2}} = \int_{-r}^{r}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx + \int_{\gamma_{r}}\frac{1}{1+z^{2}} = 2\pi i \cdot Res(f,i) = 2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{2i} = \pi$$

Now if we take $\lim_{r \rightarrow + \infty}\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx$ we obtain $$\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx = \pi$$ and so $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$